# Mixed Content error after migrating from Angular 7 to 12

Tags: angular, docker, ng-build, angular12, angular-devkit

**The stack:**
Angular 12 with .NET, running in a Docker container. Bundles are being built by @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser.

**Last working setup:**
The application ran previously on Angular 7, all the assets were indeed served over HTTPS.

**The problem:**
While running over HTTPS, Angular 12 bundle is serving assets incl. main.js, polyfills, stylesheet or favicon over HTTP. This is causing the following error for bundles, polyfills, styles.css and favicons:

> Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an
> insecure X. This request has been blocked; the content must be served
> over HTTPS.

My #1 suspect is the ng build process, although I'm not aware of a way to determine the way, the assets are served(?) Therefore I mentioned the rest of the stack to check there if needed.

**UPDATE**: I marked one answer but it's a workaround that I decided to go with as good enough, although there should be a more in-depth solution that I'm still hoping to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are upgrading `Angular 7` to `Angular 12` directly then you will get below error:

`"Updating multiple major versions at once is not recommended."`

Assuming that you have `Angular 7` installed on the project, now you need to first upgrading your application to `Angular 8`, then `Angular 8` to `Angular 9`, then `Angular 9` to `Angular 10`, then `Angular 10` to `Angular 11`:

```
ng update @angular/core@6 @angular/cli@6 --force
ng update @angular/core@7 @angular/cli@7 --force
ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8 --force
ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 --force
ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 --force
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force
```

Now, you have upgraded your `Angular 7` application to `Angular 11`, so you will run the below command to upgrade to latest `Angular 12` version:

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 --force
```

`--force` to the `ng update` command has been appended incase if it gives `"Incompatible peer dependencies found"` error.

**EDIT**

Add the following meta tag to your `<head>` element in your `HTML`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: Thanks, but again I don't believe that's the issue. Everything works in development. In production too with the exception of Dockerized build trying to fetch assets through the wrong protocol.

Comment: Can you please check with the edited version in my answer?

Comment: Thank you, adding the <meta> tag solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to skip versions while upgrading your application. Ideal way should be to upgrade 1 major version at once, i.e. 7.x -> 8.x and so on.

For a better understanding follow Angular's update guide:
https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Thanks, I think we followed this manual you are linking to. There are also no issues that are out of control, nothing is blowing up etc. other than this serving weirdness so I believe that is something that we can understand and fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable that if you are updating to `angular 13 from angular 10`, then first need to update it to `angular 11` and subsequent `12` later to `13`

```
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 --force
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force
```

Like this, the above error will not appear

*Note: Adding --force to the ng update command won't give an "Incompatible peer dependencies found" error.

I hope this will solve the Migration Bug.

Happy Coding !!!